# $$ ... $$ is centered but \[ ... \] and equation/align/gather etc. aren't

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle, center

Basically only using $$...$$ gets me a centered equation, which isn't optimal when I want to number them.

Here's the main .tex file, the file compiles normally without error...  any clue what's wrong ? Thanks !

```
\documentclass[oneside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,listof=totoc,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,american,BCOR=3mm]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}  \usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}



\geometry{paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2cm, % Inner margin
    outer=2cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=2.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\begin{document}
  \frenchspacing
  \raggedbottom
  \selectlanguage{american}
  
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  
  \singlespacing
  \input{text/ch0-title}
  \input{text/ch0-backside}
  

  
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \input{text/ch0-abstract}
  
  \input{text/ch0-acknowledgements}
  \input{text/ch0-publications}

  \onehalfspacing
  \input{text/ch0-contents}
  
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \onehalfspacing

  \chapter*{Introduction}\label{c:Introduction}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
  \input{text/ch1}
  
  \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
  \chapter{Preliminaries}\label{c:prelim}
  \input{text/ch5}
  
  \chapter{Deep learning }\label{c:deeplearning}
  \input{text/ch2}
  
  \chapter{The study of a semi-linear elliptic problem}\label{c:elliptic}
  \input{text/ch3}
  
  \chapter{The study of a time-periodic parabolic problem }\label{c:parabolic}
  \input{text/ch4}

  \chapter{Chapter 5}\label{c:applications}
  \input{text/ch6}
  
  \chapter{Conclusions}\label{c:Conclusions}
  \input{text/ch7}
  
  \cleardoublepage
  \appendix
  \chapter{Code repository}\label{c:appendix}
  \input{text/app2}
  
  
  \singlespacing
  \input{text/app-bibliography}
  \cleardoublepage
  
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \onehalfspacing


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We can not test your `\input`ed files, we simply do not have them. Please make your code compilable for us ...

Comment: When I remove all the `\input`s that we don't have, add loading `babel`, `setspace`, and `scrlayer-scrpage` to make your document actually compilable, your equations are correctly centered. Please create an example that actually shows your issue.

Comment: please always provide an example that demonstrates the probem and has no local files not supplied and has no package not needed. I would guess you have `fleqn` specified so get flush left equations. `$$` should never be usd in latex and does not honour the `fleqn` option.

Comment: Off-topic: Since your document loads the `amssymb` package, there is no rational justification for loading `latexsym` -- which last updated ca 1994 -- as well. And, since `graphicx` loads both `graphics` and `epstopdf` automatically, no discernible (valid) purpose is served by loading the latter two packages explicitly.

Comment: @Mensch i quickly linked the main .tex to see if the problem is in the way i defined the geometry/document class etc. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it was indeed because of of `fleqn`, thank you !

Comment: @Mico duly noted, thank you !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it unfortunately won't let me accept my own answer for 2 days, how do i close it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the non-compilable code, just wanted to see if I made some error in declaring the geometry or document class etc.

The problem was in another file, `classicthesis-config.tex`.

ctrl+R `fleqn`, found it in `\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}` and changed it to `\PassOptionsToPackage{}{amsmath}`.

So far it seems to work and has solved my problem.

Thanks to @DavidCarlisle for pointing it out.

Comment: You can completely remove `\PassOptionsToPackage{}{amsmath}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz noted, thank you !